# Characterization of conjugacy classes of $A_n$: intuition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Note the following theorem (quoted after [handouts by Keith Conrad (UoCT) found online](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/conjclass.pdf)):

Let $\pi \in A_n$. Its conjugacy class (cc) in $S_n$ remains the same in $A_n$, or it breaks into two cc's of equal size. It breaks iff the lengths of the cycle type of $\pi$ are *distinct odd* numbers.

It is given without proof. Related questions I have:

1) In $A_4$, I can visualize what the two cc's of cycle structure $(1,3)$ correspond to (eg, each a rotation around a vertex of a tetrahedron by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, one cc clockwise, the other counterclockwise). Is there a general intuition for what characterizes the 2 cc it breaks into?

2) It is not too hard to see that those cc's with cycle structures that operate on less than $n-1$ elements (and which have even parity) have enough freedom to translate the single cc in $S_n$ to a single one in $A_n$. This turns out to be true. Before finding the theorem, I had hypothesized as well that the converse is true too - if the sums of the integers $d \ne 1$ of the cycle structure add to $n$ or $n-1$, the single cc of $\pi$ in $S_n$ breaks into several in $A_n$. But by the theorem, eg, in $A_6$, the permutations of cycle structure $(3,3)$ are a single cc in $A_6$ as well. Is there an intuition for what makes the condition *distinct, odd* special?

Comment: I never understood how looking at tetrahedra gives people intuition for symmetric groups, but here are some hints for the proof. You are wondering when two permutations $x$ and $y$ in $S_n$ which have the same cycle type are conjugate to each other in $A_n$. In $S_n$, they are always conjugate to each other, and you prove this by writing down their cycle representations one under the other (so that cycles of equal lengths match) and then defining a permutation $z$ which sends each element in the cycle representation for $x$ to the corresponding element in the cycle representation ...

Comment: ... for $y$. Now this $z$ might not necessarily lie in $A_n$. But maybe we can fix this by modifying it. If we pick an even-length cycle of $x$ and rotate it in the cycle representation, then $z$ changes its sign (indeed, it gets multiplied by this cycle, and this cycle is odd), so that we can get $z$ into $A_n$ if $x$ has an even-length cycle. If $x$ has two odd-length cycles of the same length, then we can switch them in the cycle representation, which again changes the sign of $z$ and thus brings $z$ into $A_n$. So we are done in this case too. It remains to prove that ...

Comment: ... if $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$ into distinct odd parts, then there exist two permutations $x$ and $y$ in $A_n$ having cycle type $\lambda$ which are not conjugate in $A_n$. This is somewhat annoying. Essentially, take $x$ arbitrary, and define $y$ by switching two entries in one of the nontrivial cycles of $x$ ("nontrivial" means "length $>1$"). Argue that if $y = zxz^{-1}$, then $z$ must map each cycle of $x$ to the (unique) cycle of $y$ having the same length (although possibly rotated), and that this way you won't ever get ...

Comment: ... a $z \in A_n$ to work. There is probably a slicker argument by counting conjugacy classes and showing that there are so many of them in $A_n$ that no cc corresponding to a partition into distinct odd parts can afford not to split into two.

Comment: I seem to recall that, in $A_n$, if the class containing $\sigma$ breaks, then $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ wind up in separate classes (I hope I'm remembering that right). That at least gives computations to focus on; convincing yourself that $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ can't belong to the same class of $A_n$, if they have that particular kind of cycle structure.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: this is a great answer; why don't you copy-paste it to an answer instead of this long list of comments? In particular your second comment really helped. I convinced myself in examples that your claims on the parity change of $z$ are true in the two cases, and this is the meat of it for me. I'll sit down tomorrow trying to make it formal for myself.

Comment: Others can do a better job at putting my proof into words -- the notion of a good answer on m.se is stricter than "helps the OP". But glad it helped you!

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Allow me one final question to confirm I get this as intended: in comment 2, part 2 (case of 2 cycles of equal odd length), the argument you use does not rely on the cycle length of the 2 cycles being odd, just on their length being equal (you apply a bijection moving 2k elements (whether k odd or even), resulting in a change of sign(z) by -1 (as "sign(2k) =-1"), correct?

Comment: I think it does use the oddness of their length. Think of it as a permutation which sends $1, 2, \ldots, k, k+1, k+2, \ldots, 2k$ to $k+1, k+2, \ldots, 2k, 1, 2, \ldots, k$, respectively (upon relabelling the elements of the cycles). The sign of this permutation is $\left(-1\right)^{k^2} = \left(-1\right)^k$, which is negative if and only if $k$ is odd.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Get it now - it's like k transpositions, so we need k odd. Thanks again!

Comment: @ pjs36: Actually, going over it again, I noticed: Look at a full even cycle of length n, n odd, $n \ge 5$, in $A_n$. Relabel, so $\pi$ = (1 2 ... n), $\pi^{-1}$ = (1 n ... 2). Then $\pi^{-1} = z \pi z^{-1}$ for z = (2 n)(3 n-1) ... ($\frac{n+1}{2} (\frac{n+1}{2}+1))$). The number of transpositions is even iff n =1 mod 4, so at least in that case (mod condition, full odd cycle), $\pi$ and $\pi^{-1}$ are conjugate in $A_n$.

Comment: As in the case n = 3 mod 4 any other resulting z comes after cyclically rotating $\pi$ by a cycle of odd length $n$ (sign =1), it also shows that in the 3 mod 4 case, for full cycles, a permutation and its inverse are not conjugate in $A_n$. So getting an intuition might be hard.